# is it possible to create in java hashmap that keeps its initial length?

Tags: java, hashmap, maps, capacity

I want to create hashMap

```
private Map<Integer,specificObject> myMap;
myMap = new HashMap <Integer,SpecificObject>(initialCapacity);
```

is it possible that myMap capacity will remain the same for the entire program?
even if we've reached the full capacity.

Comment: What do you expect to happen once you reach capacity?

Comment: Can you fill a bottle with a higher volume of water than the volume of the bottle ? Basically, no. If you want to prevent the capacity to change, you have to keep a number of objects in the HashMap lower than loadFactor * capacity.

Comment: I don't want its length to be changed.. for example if I reached the capacity I'd like it to throw an exception perhaps..

Comment: Is it possible to use a regular array? It's size is final and you can access/assign by index

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method which checks the current size of hashmap and throw a custom exception if the size is greater than n , where n is the max capacity you want.

Now, in the code add a call to above method before you write map.put.

This will ensure that you dont add elements to map when it exceeds your custom limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such a class yourself.  (The obvious approach would be to create a wrapper class for `HashMap` that checked the map's size, etcetera each time you called `put`.)

However, the regular `HashMap` class doesn't work that way.  And furthermore, the `initialCapacity` parameter is:

- not the map's size,
- not the *actual* number of entries<sup>1</sup> you can store before the map needs to be expanded, and
- not exposed via an accessible variable or getter.

---

<sup>1 - That number is determined by a formula involving the initial capacity and the load factor.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, the `initialCapacity` is not the real capacity.

When you pass `12`, the capacity is `16`, which means that you pass a, the system will use `b >= a` and mostly reaching `2^N`.

Second, in hashmap, there is a `factor = most num / all capacity`. For example, if factor = 0.5, and  the capacity is 16, when you put 8 objects, the size will extending automatically.

Answer (score 0):

While the Java standard library does not have a size limiting cache implementation, Google's Guava has such a class. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Size-based_Eviction. Cache has the same interface as a Map with additional functionality like size limiting, timeout on entries, etc that can be defined when creating the cache.